# Unbind Slide Method from jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I want to override/overwrite the slide method of a jQuery UI slider after the slider has been initialized with a certain slide function.

Relevant code is show below and in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ff9S/1/):

```
$(function() {
    var myslider = $("#myslider");
    $( myslider ).slider({
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log("sliding AAAAA");
        } //end slide function
    });//end slider definition

    //how do I unbind the original slide action?
    $(myslider).off("slide");     //doesn't work
    $(myslider).unbind("slide");  //doesn't work

    $(myslider).on("slide", function( event, ui ) {
        //I want this to be the only action fired.
        console.log("sliding BBBBB");
    });
});
```

In the example/fiddle above, both actions are still firing when the user slides the slider.  How can I make it so only the 2nd `slide` method gets fired, thus overwriting the first one?

Thanks!

### EDIT

I'm not sure this is the "right" way to do this, but it appears to work:

```
$(myslider).slider("option","slide","");
```

Perhaps I should enter this as my answer to my own question?  But I assume there's a better more defined/designed way, so I'll leave it open.

Comment: The method is already set, so setting it again just adds to the object. You probably have to destroy the slider and initialize a new one with the new slide paremeter.

Comment: You can safely post your edit as an answer. For what it's worth, the root cause is that specifying the `slide` option is not actually the same thing as binding to the `slide` event (a key difference is that bound handlers are called first in the current implementation). The magic lies in the base widget's `_trigger()` method. So you do have to clear the option to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best answer I have to my own question:

```
$(myslider).slider("option","slide",""); //clear the slide option
```

If there's a better or cleaner or more "jQuery" way to do it, please post it.

### EDIT

Or, as @FrédéricHamidi's comment suggests, set the `slide` option to null (instead of empty string).  Both will achieve the effect of overwriting an existing `slide` function.

```
$(myslider).slider("option","slide",null); //clear the slide option
```

Comment: Now that you mention it, I would probably set the option to `null` instead of the empty string, but that's borderline nitpicking. Well, unless the first part of the code in your question is under your control, but then you could just omit the `slide` option, and you probably wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.